Implement server side idle timeout logic
I’m looking for suggestions on how to manage session timeouts for a Heygen video streaming avatar in my web application. Currently, their default timeout is 2 minutes of inactivity, after which the session ID is automatically terminated. However, I need the idle timeout to be 3 minutes for my application.
Since Heygen doesn’t allow modifying the timeout duration directly, they provide a parameter called disable_timeout. By setting this to true, I can disable their default timeout and implement my own server-side logic to detect idle time. My goal is to track 3 minutes of inactivity on the server and then call the streaming.stop API to terminate the session.
The challenge is to track idle timeout entirely on the server without relying on any signals from the client. Does anyone have ideas or best practices on how to achieve this effectively?
I tried implementing a solution using an in-memory HashMap to track session IDs and their expiration timestamps. Every 10 seconds, a periodic check runs to determine if any sessions have exceeded their timeout duration.
While this approach works, it has limitations:
Increased Server Load: As the number of sessions grows, frequent checks increase the load on the server.
Scalability Issues: This method is not efficient for handling a large number of concurrent sessions, especially in a distributed environment where multiple server instances might be running.
Data Volatility: Since the session data is stored in-memory, it is lost if the server restarts or crashes.
I was expecting a more efficient and scalable way to handle this, such as leveraging a tool like Redis with built-in expiration or designing a system with better resource management.
